# Coefficients of first fundamental form in geodesic parallel coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In Do Carmo's *Differental Geometry of curves and surfaces*, Chap.4-6, the geodesic polar coordinate system is introduced.
A geometrical interpretation of Gaussian curvature in geodesic polar coordinate of a curve $\vec{R}(\rho,\theta)$ we get when $E=1, F=0$ is

> $K=-\frac{\sqrt{G}_{\rho\rho}}{\sqrt{G}}$, and $\sqrt{G}=\rho-\frac{K_p}{6}\rho^3+o(\rho^3)$

In geodesic parallel coordinates, the surface is constructed by this:
First, we have a surface $\vec{r}: D\to \mathbb{R}^3$ and a curve $c: [-1,1]\to D$, so $\vec{\gamma}(s):=\vec{r} \circ c$ is an arc length parameterized curve on the surface.
$\forall t \in [-1,1]$, we can define $\xi_t: [-\delta,\delta](\subseteq [-1,1]) \to D$ such that $(\vec{r} \circ \xi_t)(s)$ is a geodesic on the surfacr  satisfying the geodesic ODEs, with the initial value $$(\vec{r} \circ \xi_t)(0)=\gamma(t);  \frac{d}{ds}|_{s=0}(\vec{r} \circ \xi_t)=\frac{d\vec\gamma}{dt}(t) \times \vec{n}(\vec\gamma(t))$$
Then, we can define the geodesic parallel coordinated curve $\vec{R}(s,t):=(\vec{r} \circ \xi_t)(s)$

In this parametrization, there is also a similar formula about Gaussian curvature, where $\kappa_g$ is the geodesic curvature of $\vec\gamma$:

> $E=1, F=0, \sqrt{G}=1+\kappa_g(t)s-\frac{K_p}{2}s^2+o(s^2)$

So my problem is, how can we get this relation of $\sqrt{G}$? I can't see how it's related to the geodesic curvature. Maybe there's something to do with the Liouville's formula of geodesic curvature?

Thanks in advance.